# Creating a matrix in R?

Tags: r, matrix

I want to generate the matrix below by using a R statement.

1)

```
0 1 1
1 0 1
1 1 0
```

2)

```
0 2 3
0 5 0
7 0 0
```

3)

```
1  3  5  7
3  7 11 15
7 15 23 31
```

I need to write a function? diag function doesn't help for the first question.

Comment: Please read one of the many introductory text books to R.

Comment: These are not diagonal matrices.

Answer (score 1):

```
a1 <- matrix(c(0,1,1,
               1,0,1,
               1,1,0),
             nrow=3, ncol=3, byrow=TRUE)
```

The others work similar.